# Do I need services.AddMvc or not?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to find out why in all docs I see `services.AddMvc` or `services.AddMvcCore` in Startup.cs
but in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 template that's created by VS I do not have AddMvc but mvc still works....

the only thing I have related t MVC is

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

can anyone explain why?

Comment: I think all the docs you are seeing is for .net core 2.*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @ManishTiwari  is correct

Comment: I am adding a new answer, so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all the docs you are seeing is for .net core 2.*.
 For More Information -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 12):

As the doc has said that asp.net core 3.0+ template use these new 
methods`AddControllersWithViews`,`AddRazorPages`,`AddControllers` instead of `AddMvc`.

However, `AddMvc` continues to behave as it has in previous releases.`AddMvc()` is really just a wrapper around a bunch of other methods that register services. See Source:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0303c9e90b5b48b309a78c2ec9911db1812e6bf3/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27

You could either use `AddMvc` to register for MVC, Razor Pages,API or use individual `AddControllersWithViews`(for MVC only) and `AddRazorPages` (for Razor Pages only).

Comment: What would you do if you have a mixture of mvc, razor pages and web api endpoints?