# Http Client POST Requests with complex json value in .NET Core 5 web app

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I work with project asp core 5.0, I call external API to my API Controller using HTTP Client
and The error

**A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.**

Controller.cs

```cs
public async Task<AuthDataAttributesResponseDTO> AuthenticationTest(AuthDTO input)
{

    var model = new AuthDataAttributesDTO
    {
        type = "authentication",
        attributes = input
    };

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://X.XX.XX.XX/api/v1/oauth2/access-token", content))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthDataAttributesResponseDTO>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488872/error-when-deserialize-json-net-core-5-jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `System.Text.Json`, you can add this code into `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(option =>
{
    option.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

> The `AddControllersWithViews()` can also be `AddControllers()` or `AddMvc()`, it depends which you are using.

If you're using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

If you can not find `AddNewtonsoftJson()`, try to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` nuget package.

Comment: where can I add this code
which line  Do you mean in Startup.cs

Comment: If you have the Startup.cs, yes. You can add it in ConfigureServices, and use services to replace builder.Services