# A possible object cycle was detected. This can be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32

Tags: c#, api

I have encountered really weird situation. I am developing a net 5 api, and (among ohther entities) have three tables, Doctor, Specialization, and DoctorSpecialization. My entities:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }           
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Resume { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorSpecialization1> DoctorSpecializations { get; set; }       
}

public class DoctorSpecialization
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int Doctor1Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Doctor1Id")]
    public Doctor1 Doctor { get; set; }

    public int Specialization1Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Specialization1Id")]
    public Specialization1 Specialization { get; set; }
}

public class Specialization
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string SpecializationName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to fetch all the specializations associated with the certain doctor, therefore I created a service:

```
public class DoctorService : IDoctorService
{
    public async Task<List<Specialization>> GetAllSpecializationsForDoctor(int id)
    {
        var doctor = await _context.Doctors.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var doctorSpecializations = await _context.DoctorSpecializations.
                                    Where(x => x.DoctorId == doctor.Id)
                                   .ToListAsync();
        
        IEnumerable<int> ids = doctorSpecializations.Select(x => x.SpecializationId);

        var specializations = await _context.Specializations.Where(x => 
        ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToListAsync();
        return specializations;
    }     
}
```

In the end, I am adding a method in my controller which is supposed to fetch specializations based on doctor's id:

```
[HttpGet("specializations/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Specialization1>>> GetSpecializationsForDoctor(int id)
{
    var doctor = await _doctorService.FindDoctorById(id);

    if (doctor == null) return NotFound();

    var specialization = _doctorService.GetAllSpecializationsForDoctor(id);
    
    return Ok(specialization);
}
```

When I run this in postman, I get the error stated in the title of this question. However, I encountered an article that explains I should install newtonsoft.json and make some changes in my Startup in order to overcome this issue. So therefore I installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.10" and made changes in my Starup as follows:

```
 services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
 Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

This time I get the expected result, but my postman shows tons of data before giving me the wanted result, and I wonder is it ok to return this much data to the client. Can somebody explain me what is going on, tnx in advance!

Comment: Why do your entity names have a number on when used in a prop but not when defined?

Comment: soprry, I corrected that, I was doing all sorts of testing in my project

Comment: It sounds like your serializer is getting caught in some cycle of trying to serialize eg a Doctor (let's call him Jekyll) who has a list of DoctorSpecializations which each have a Doctor, which is Doctor Jekyll, who has a list of DoctorSpecializations which each have a Doctor, which is Doctor Jekyll, who has a list of DoctorSpecializations which each have a Doctor, which is Doctor Jekyll, who ..

Comment: Don't serialize the db entities EF made for you because it implicitly creates cycles in its graph when it wires up relationships. Map to DTOs instead that have a finite reach/are only singly directionally linked

Comment: what do you suggest, should I rewrite the query?

Comment: I'm not sure I have any suggestion further to what I noted above; I've never encountered this because I don't send my DB entities for ser to the front end - I have a different set of objects, call them Dto or ViewModel or whatever, that encapsulate just the data the front end is interested in, and the graph is acyclic; my DoctorDto would have a List of SpecialismDto but a Specialism wouldn't link back to a Doctor. Libraries like AutoMapper, AgileMapper, Mapster can create and populate these DTOs for you so it's no bother to have them, ans they can massively cut down on the data transited

Comment: tnx for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution was so simple, I missed the await in:

```
        var specialization = await 
 _doctorService.GetAllSpecializationsForDoctor(id);
```

Once again I managed to find solution thanks to stackoverflow, because apparently someone else had this problem in: [JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197270/jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported-this)

So please everyone, don't be so superficial as I was, make sure to use await and save your time. Thanks again to the community:).

Answer (score 0):

You should not return entities from your controllers. Instead make use of DTOs. I had the same issue and it was related to returning the entire entity with it relations.