# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API - serializing public fields

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have the requirement that my web controller needs to return a class with only public fields.
E.g. I have

```cs
public class RunningScenario
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

and want to return this from my controller like  this

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ScenarioController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("start")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<RunningScenario>> StartScenario(int scenarioId)
    {
        // Error handling

        var runningScenario = await _scenariorRunner.Start(scenarioId);
        return Ok(runningScenario);
    }
}
```

Though, running this just returns `{}` instead of `{"Id": 1, "Name": "Scenario 1"}`.

I also tried to add the `[JsonInclude]` attribute to the fields, with no effect. The result is still an empty object.

So, my question is, how do I get the public fields to be serialized and deserialized?

Comment: Do not use fields, use properties instead. If  you cannot change the fields to properties, then create a new class and map the class to the new class and return the new class.

Comment: In the `Program.cs` file you might able to configure `JsonSerializerOptions` by setting `IncludeFields` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you, Fred , sadly I can't avoid using fields, because I am sharing this class with a Unity client and there serialization only works with fields and not properties. That's why I am stuck with fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of aspnet use the json serializer from `System.Text.Json` by default instead of `Newtonsoft.Json`. By default the serializer of `System.Text.Json` will not serialize fields, unlike `Newtonsoft.Json`.

The better option is to make the fields properties (e.g. `public string Name { get; set; }`). If that's really not an option you can adjust the settings of the serializer in your startup. E.g.

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});
```

Comment: An alternative would be to create a DTO class, such as `RunningScenarioDto` and map the fields from `RunningScenario` to the corresponding properties in the DTO class.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue in .net 6, by adding this to the Program.cs file:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
builder.Services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Check this solution: [JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197270/jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported-this)