# C# .net core 6.0 Web API A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-6.0

**Error**

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path:

My code - model class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Manager> Managers { get; set; } = new List<Manager>();
}

public class Manager
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; } = new List<Customer>();
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomers()
{
    if (_context.Customers == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await _context.Customers.Include(c => c.Managers).AsSingleQuery().ToListAsync();
}
```

**Details**

There is a n-to-m relationship between `Customer` and `Manager`, and there is a loop when using `Include()` queries. When I run my project, it throws a error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path:

**Resolution**

**Method #1**: I set `System.Text.Json.JsonException` in my `program.cs`.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 0;
    });
```

If I set `MaxDepth = 0`, it can't get `Managers` in Customers Info in my API, so I set `MaxDepth = 1`, then I get a new error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The object or value could not be serialized. Path:

I don't how to address it,then I tried the following method.

**Method #2**: I used the Nuget `Newtonsoft.Json`, set in my `program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Then there were no errors in the code, but with the increasing of data, the execution speed became very slow. It was only then that I realized that loops actually existed and were ignored. By default, executed 32 layers.

**Method #3**: I add `[JsonIgnore]` in the model of `Manager`:

```
public class Manager
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; } = new List<Customer>();
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json and `[JsonIgnore]`, my code runs normally, and the looping problem no longer exists. But you know If I want get Customers in a Manager, it can't run because I used `[JsonIgnore]` in `Manager`, if I don't use `[JsonIgnore]`, in my query action use

```
await _context.Customers
              .Include(c => c.Managers)
              .SelectMany(c => Managers)
              .AsSingleQuery().ToListAsync()
```

it throws an error

> Compiler Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'

So what should I do to resolve this error?

I referred to this link：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197270/jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported-this

Comment: Could your create a minimal sample which could reproduce the issue for us? We need the repo to investigate the issue and please hide your sensitive information.

Comment: @Jason Pan I have already pushed the demo to Github Repo. As a beginner, I have tried many methods but have not solved this problem. Thank you for your help.    https://github.com/Soberuser/ErrorDemo

Comment: Using `[JsonIgnore]` to fix the loop issue is a good choice. What's the current issue ？

Comment: I can't find the `Compiler Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'` error.

Comment: Because the customer class and manager class have a many to many relationship, when using [JsonIgnore], customers cannot be obtained through the manager, such as Github's demo. The getmanagers appi only returns the first layer of information, and include (o=>o. customers) cannot work.

Comment: Is there a error with the demo in my repo? I use the Sqlite database and have configured the path in the TestContext. It should not need to be modified and can be run directly.

Comment: IMHO Don't serialise your data model. Create a view model for each json result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `.Include` method with the following method, which does not require `[JsonIgnore]` to achieve many to many queries from Customer to Managers and from Manager to Customer.

Before:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomers()
{
    if (_context.Customers == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return await _context.Customers.Include(o=>o.Managers).ToListAsync();
}
```

Now:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomersNow()
{
    if (_context.Customers == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return await (from customer in _context.Customers select new Customer { Id=customer.Id, Name=customer.Name, Managers=customer.Managers }).ToListAsync();
}
```

I have pushed the demonstration case to the [github repo Soberuser/ErrorDemo](https://github.com/Soberuser/ErrorDemo), where you can download and run it. There are two interfaces that generate loops,`http://localhost:5078/test/getmanagers`, `http://localhost:5078/test/getcustomers` and two normal interfaces`http://localhost:5078/test/getcustomersnow`, `http://localhost:5078/test/getmanagersnow`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Class as bellow:

```
public class CustomerManager
{
    public ulong CustomerId { get; set; }
    public ulong ManagerId { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Managers)
        .WithMany(e => e.Customers)
        .UsingEntity<CustomerManager>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should use ”.UsingEntity<CustomerManager>();“ instead of ”.UsingEntity<CustomerManagers>();“, right?   
I have tried what you said,Add-Mirgration ,Update-Database, deleted [JsonIgnore], Program.cs uses NewtonsoftJson's Ignore, but the loop still exists. The Managers in Customer have customers-managers-customers...

Comment: Yes. Sorry my bad. It should be .UsingEntity<CustomerManager>();